# How should I reattach this garage door bracket?

Tags: doors, garage

I didn't install this originally but looks like the bracket has broke off from the door. Also it appears that the door itself is damaged. What is the best way to repair this?

[image: Bracket]

[image: door]

Comment: I can't tell what I'm looking at. Where on the door was this thing? Do you get the impression that it was a handle, or a motion stop of some sort?

Comment: @isherwood that is the arm that connects to the door there is usually a quick disconnect to be able to open the door if the power is out.

Answer (score 1):

Once screws rip out I like to reenforced the door.
I would get a larger piece of metal several inches wider. And screw into the door in 2-3 new locations if in the center use flat head screws there. Then attach the original bracket to the new piece of metal.

Next I would check that the door moves up with only a few pounds of force. I have found garage like you have when the torsion or one of the torsion springs break. If the door feels like more than 30lb you may want to inspect your spring(s). Broken springs are not hard to replace but can be quite dangerous (believe it or not even fatal at times). Door pros can knock a broken spring out quickly. 
This may be the reason the bracket ripped loose.

Comment: I agree. I've actually mounted two-by lumber between the two reinforcing ribs, screwing through them into the wood and through the wood into the door skin. The bracket can be mounted at any height in the top half of the upper panel (it doesn't have to be right at the top), but the opener travel will need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to remove the existing screws from the bracket and fit the bracket back into place on the door. It appears that the lower lip on the bracket gets inserted behind the metal channel on the door. Line up the holes in the door with the holes in the bracket. Drill through the bracket holes with the same size drill all the way through the door. Get some bolts long enough to go through the door from the outside, with a washer, through the bracket then another washer and then a nut. tighten up everything and that should do it. Good luck.